# Cannot find module ts-node - assuming path or parcel is the problem

Tags: node.js, typescript, ts-node

I'm trying to run [swell/svala](https://github.com/clarinsi/swell-editor). After running yarn and using `yarn run serve` the app starts but throws an error:

> ×  Cannot find module 'path\to\svala$(ts-node' from 'path\to\svala'

This project is foreign to me and I've never worked with ts-node and parcel. After doing a bunch of googling, most links leads to SO Q&A, where the main culprit is usually the path.

This is the relevant command found in package.json

```
    "serve": "parcel $(ts-node src/generate_index.ts ${App:-Editor})",
```

I've also tried changing the command to include the "correct path", but I get almost the same error mesagge.

```
    "serve": "parcel $(node_modules/ts-node src/generate_index.ts ${App:-Editor})",
```

> ×  Cannot find module 'path\to\svala$(node_modules\ts-node' from
> 'path\to\svala'

The problem might not be the path, but something with parcel, but I have no idea what `$( ... )` is supposed to do.

Like I said, I'm not really sure whats going on here, so I would like to ask for help resolving this problem.

Module ts-node is located inside svala\node_modules\ts-node

This is tsconfig-json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "strict": true,
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "jsx": "react",
    "lib": ["es2017", "dom"],
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "allowUnreachableCode": true,
    "keyofStringsOnly": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true
  },
  "include": ["src", "test"],
  "parcelTsPluginOptions": {
    "transpileOnly": false
  }
}
```

If I can provide any additional information, please let me know.

Thank you

**Edit 1:**
As requested, adding stacktrace.

```
×  Cannot find module path\to\svala\$(ts-node' from 'path\to\svala'
    at Resolver.resolve (path\to\svala\node_modules\parcel-bundler\src\Resolver.js:76:17)
    at async Bundler.resolveAsset (path\to\svala\node_modules\parcel-bundler\src\Bundler.js:308:23)
    at async Bundler.bundle (path\to\svala\node_modules\parcel-bundler\src\Bundler.js:182:26)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to install ubuntu to run yarn. Then everything worked. I guess it's not compatibile with windows (`rm` and such)

Comment: I am glad you got it working @WeAreDoomed

Answer (score 1):

Please can you add a stack trace of what you are getting in terminal?

Also, are there any critical compiler options for Typescript that you know of? i.e, are any of those options in your `tsconfig.json` specific to the project `swell/svala`, or can you slim down the compiler options?

I am posting a slimmed down `tsconfig.json` I generally use for my TypeScript projects.

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es2015",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "allowJs": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "outDir": "./dist",
        "importHelpers": true,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "lib": ["es2018"]
    },
    "include": ["./src"],
    "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

If you provide more information I might be able to help more :)

Comment: Hey, thanks for checking this out. stacktrace added.

Comment: @WeAreDoomed, just a few remarks. You are using multiple technologies (like `parcel`, `ts-node`, etc) I would recommend cutting `ts-node`, i.e compile your TS code to JS via `tsc`, then try and run it. I am also not sure what `parcel` is, it looks like a build tool which I am not sure if you need it.

IMHO: Try and execute the code in the most minimalist fashion first, then add back the other pieces of tech to the execution/compilation stack. This will help with debug-ability

Comment: I agree. There is too much stuff here, especially if many of them are new (to me). The problem with that is, that I don't know what is actually required and what is "redundent".
Figured out the command which actually lets me run/compile generate_index.js, but the page is blank. It's something I guess...

Comment: Maybe try and run the js file with `node src/generate_index.ts` and leave `parcel` out of it. Or you could even `npm i nodemon` and then `nodemon src/generate_index.ts`